ValueNotifier listener not being canceled on dispose, and related questions
Questions about using a ValueNotifier listener:

In addListener, should the VoidCallback listener be specified with or without the final parentheses, i.e., flagUpdated.addListener(() => doScreenRefresh()); or flagUpdated.addListener(() => doScreenRefresh); ? While I've seen many examples of code online showing it without the parentheses, when I leave out the paranetheses, the listener is never called. It is only called when I include the final parantheses.

In removeListener, the IDE only allows me to specify the function without final parentheses. However, even after dispose, the listener continues to capture changes to flagUpdated. Thus, I am finding it impossible to to cancel the listener. What is the correct way to cancel the listener?

From what I've read, there is actually no need to explicitly call removeListener in the override dispose method, because upon dispose, all listeners are canceled. However, whether or not I include the removeListener call in dispose, the listener continues to capture changes to flagUpdated. So, same question, what is the correct way to cancel the listener?

When the screen is disposed (as confirmed by seeing the "Disposing now" message in the console, the screen object apparently continues to exist, even though it is not mounted. In fact, if the user navigates to this screen 10 times and it is subsequently disposed 10 times, any change to flagUpdated will trigger the listener in the supposedly-non-existent screen 10 times! I know this because I am seeing in the console this message 10 times for each change in value of flagUpdated: "In doScreenRefresh, mounted=false". (I only need doScreenRefresh to execute when the screen is visible and mounted.) Why isn't the screen object itself completely destroyed after it is disposed?


I have been experimenting with different approaches for hours, and researching online, but I have not been able to figure this out. The skeleton of my code is below.
Thank you.
// A global app variable
final ValueNotifier<bool> flagUpdated = ValueNotifier(false); 

class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flagUpdated.addListener(() => doScreenRefresh());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    debugPrint("Disposing now");
    flagUpdated.removeListener(doScreenRefresh);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void doScreenRefresh() {
    debugPrint("In doScreenRefresh, mounted=$mounted"); 
    // Do something
  }
  
  void closeMe() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("Other");
  }
  
}

// Elsewhere in the app, this is used to run doScreenRefresh() above
flagUpdated.value = true; // or false, whichever new value causes the change trigger

Flutter doctor:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4412], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.89.1)


  @override
  void initState() {
    flagUpdated.addListener(doScreenRefresh);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flagUpdated.removeListener(doScreenRefresh);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void doScreenRefresh() {
    debugPrint("In doScreenRefresh, mounted=$mounted");
    // Do something
  }

1、2: You should define a method and ensure that both addListener and removeListener reference this method, so that the object being added and removed is the same.
3: You must properly remove the listener in the dispose method.
4: Because the method objects you added and removed are not the same, the callback still exists in _listeners.

Thanks for the reply @choykarl, but I don't think you addressed my questions. In the code example I sent you, are both addListener and removeListener not already referencing the same method (doScreenRefresh)? As indicated in my original post, If I remove the final parentheses in addListener, the listener doesn't work at all, and the IDE does not allow me to include the final parentheses in removeListener, so what is the solution to this? And why, after dispose, does the listener (or SomeScreen) still exist at all?
